# Use reCAPTCHA v2 in the background?

Tags: javascript, user-interface, recaptcha

I'm trying to work out if it's possible to use Google's reCAPTCHA v2 service to check if someone is human *in the background* to make the user experience even more simple?

For example, if I have something I want to let users do which involves them just pressing one button ("like" for example) and I want to check if they're human, adding an extra checkbox for them to tick makes the task twice as hard for the user.

I know reCAPTCHA uses some user tracking and other metrics to decide if someone is human, and I was wondering if I can leverage these measures without showing the reCAPTCHA checkbox every time? If it comes back "we're not sure if this person is human" then we could show the checkbox or the full-blown text guessing dialogue box, but for most users I want it to be as simple as possible.

Comment: Since recaptcha displays the challenge in an iframe full of scripts that track mouse movemenet, I highly doubt what you ask about is doable.